# Wordpress: Unable to install plugins from wp-cli

Tags: wordpress, wp-cli

Hi I am using a Ubuntu system. I am using a shell script to download wordpress from wget, update config and run it from nginx server.

Now I want to update this shell script so that when we install a fresh copy of WordPress, I get some plugins pre-installed. 
So I installed wp-cli and ran the command

```
wp plugin install w3-total-cache --activate --allow-root
```

This command says the plugin has been activated successfully. But when I go to the site URL in the plugins section, it gives the following error

`The plugin w3-total-cache/w3-total-cache.php has been deactivated due to an error: Plugin file does not exist.`

This is true for any plugin that I try to install.

When I go to the plugins folder inside wp-content, I can see that plugin files exist. But still I get the error.

How to resolve this. Please help

Comment: Do the plugin files exist, or not?

Comment: Yes the plugin files exist

Comment: May be this article can help you: http://wp-cli.org/commands/plugin/install/

Comment: I have already read that article.

Comment: Have you modified the path to your plugins folder? What happens if you manually install a plugin from the admin panel?

Answer (score 0):

You should try uploading the plugin by logging in to your wp-adm

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the latest version of wp-cli?

Try: `wp cli check-update`